# Is the 'type' attribute necessary for <script> tags?

Tags: html

I've seen both this:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

and this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Does the type attribute matter in any way?

Comment: I have never seen a script not execute because of a missing type attribute.  I'm guessing it is an issue of what is most correct, but I'm interested to see what answers are offered.

Comment: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp):

 ```In HTML5, the type attribute is no longer required for JavaScript. The default value is "application/javascript".```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

For **HTML 4.x**, the `type` attribute is **required**. [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT)

> This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.

---

For **HTML 5**, it is **optional**. If it is not specified, it defaults to `text/javascript`. [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150422034932/http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Recommendation: See **HTML 5.2**

---

For **HTML 5.2**, it **should be omitted if using a valid JavaScript MIME type** (e.g. `text/javascript`). [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-type)

> Omitting the attribute, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the charset, async, and defer attributes. Authors should omit the attribute, instead of redundantly giving a JavaScript MIME type.

Comment: Also if you use intrinsic event scripts in HTML4 (like in `onload`, `onclick`, `onmouseover` attributes etc.) you have to define `<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">` in `<head>` or configure your server to send `Content-Script-Type: text/javascript` in HTTP headers.

Comment: type="text/javascript" should be omitted per HTML 5.2 documentation. See @Scott C Wilson's answer below.

Answer (score 97):

in HTML5 you do not need the `type` attribute, but in HTML<=4 and (X)HTML it should be declared

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli : all browsers are _required_ to support the `<script>` HTML tag, ignoring its contents if they don't support the scripting language.

Answer (score 14):

The HTML 5.2 standard (late 2017) says you should omit the type attribute.

> The type attribute allows customization of the type of script represented:
>
> Omitting the attribute, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the charset, async, and defer attributes. **Authors should omit the attribute**, instead of redundantly giving a JavaScript MIME type.

(emphasis mine.)

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-type

Answer (score 7):

For testing purposes it WILL work without effect, but W3C requires it to validate correctly. The HTML 5 draft doesn't call for it as a requirement, but that is still in draft form at the W3C and they aren't recommending it.

Any browser that matters will parse it fine though.

Answer (score 6):

No, the 'type' attribute is not needed in  tags. Unless you want your code to validate.

We've been omitting it for years at work, and it's never been an issue. We test heavily across multiple devices, browsers, etc. This includes various HTML4 & XHTML doctypes.

I created this little page for testing on github:
http://kenshub.github.io/script-type.html

Answer (score 5):

According to W3C it is required: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html

Comment: Regardless of what browsers currently do, you're much better off following the standard, for better interoperability and forward-compatibility.

Comment: But not for much longer: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script: *"The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript"."*  Mind you, **I'll** keep using it, regardless.

Comment: Despite what the W3C says, in the real world, it's not required.

Comment: The link here is to the HTML 4 spec.

As per other comments, the type attribute is not required by modern browsers.

'The HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type.' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes

Answer (score 1):

The type attribute is required in HTML4.01 but optional in HTML5.
The type shows what type to be parsed.

Source:[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp),[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> NOTE: if the type attribute is a audio, HTML, video, or any MIME type besides JavaScript the code will NOT be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Though type attribute is not necessary it is helpful in most of the cases. IE works fine with out that but some times chrome and FF will cause an issue especially if the script is large.
I faced issue with type attribute while working on plotly js library. With out the type attribute IE is able to show the graphs but FF, Chrome and edge. After having added type attribute chrome and FF are able to show the charts/graphs

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of HTML, such as HTML 4 and XHTML, the `type` attribute is required for the `script` tag.

However in **HTML 5**, the `type` attribute is not necessary for the `script` tag, If you're using a regular JavaScript script, you can omit the type attribute, and the browser will assume it's a JavaScript script (`text/javascript`) by default.

but, if you're using a module script in JavaScript and want to use the import statement, you must include the `type="module"` attribute in the `script` tag.
Similarly, if you're using a WebAssembly script, you must include the type=`"wasm"` attribute in the script tag to indicate that it's a WebAssembly script in HTML5.

In summary, **if you're using HTML5, you can omit the type attribute for JavaScript scripts**, but it's still recommended to include it and specify the correct MIME type for compatibility with different web browsers and to make your code more readable for other developers. And **for the earlier versions of HTML, you have to include the `type` attribute** and set it to the appropriate value for your script.