# Do I still need to include type="value" in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

Do I need to include type="value" in my page when linking my external style sheet or script? I thought I heard it was no longer needed in HTML5. I still see it in some HTML files. Still learning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags

Comment: Not quite a duplicate; the other question is only about script tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not needed in HTML5 but in HTML<=4 or XHTML it's required.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is no longer required. The MIME type is also sent via the HTTP `Content-Type` header, so using `type="text/css"` would only be extra bytes.

Answer (score 7):

The rules for each different element are varying in HTML5.

The `<script>` element has a *default value* of `type="text/javascript"` defined for the element:

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

The `<link>` element merely uses the attribute as a 'hint' to the browser:

> For external resource links, the type attribute is used as a hint to user agents so that they can avoid fetching resources they do not support. If the attribute is present, then the user agent must assume that the resource is of the given type (even if that is not a valid MIME type, e.g. the empty string). If the attribute is omitted, but the external resource link type has a default type defined, then the user agent must assume that the resource is of that type. If the UA does not support the given MIME type for the given link relationship, then the UA should not obtain the resource; if the UA does support the given MIME type for the given link relationship, then the UA should obtain the resource at the appropriate time as specified for the external resource link's particular type. If the attribute is omitted, and the external resource link type does not have a default type defined, but the user agent would obtain the resource if the type was known and supported, then the user agent should obtain the resource under the assumption that it will be supported.
>
> User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the type attribute to determine its actual type. Only the actual type (as defined in the next paragraph) is used to determine whether to apply the resource, not the aforementioned assumed type.

The `<style>` element is similar to a script, with a *default value* of `type="text/css"`:

> The type attribute gives the styling language. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type that designates a styling language. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/css".

You can find all the information you need at the [HTML5 specifications](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `type` attribute is not required for the script tag in HTML5, but it's still a good practice to include it and specify the correct MIME type for your `script`. If you're using a regular JavaScript script, you can omit the type attribute, and the browser will assume it's a JavaScript script (`text/javascript`)  by default.

However, if you're using a module script in JavaScript and want to use the import statement, you must include the `type="module"` attribute in the script tag.

Similarly, if you're using a WebAssembly script, you must include the type=`"wasm"` attribute in the script tag to indicate that it's a WebAssembly script.

Regardless of whether you're using a regular JavaScript script, a module script, or a WebAssembly script, it's still recommended to include the type attribute and specify the correct MIME type to ensure compatibility with different web browsers and to make your code more readable for other developers.