# link file extension correction

Tags: html, hosting, webserver

I was just crafting some html for a webpage on a local server on my mac. I added a link to a stylesheet stored on my local server, but forgot to add the ".css" file extension in the href attribute. I didn't realize my mistake until I uploaded my files to an externally hosted server--because somehow the stylesheet could be found without the extension on my local server, whereas when I tried to load the page from the external server the extension was not assumed and my styles didn't load.

What entity figured out my error and corrected it locally, and why wasn't my error corrected when the page was hosted externally?

Comment: it could be the browser itself. were you using an IDE internal browser to view your local development? were you using two different browsers?

Comment: I was using the same browser in both cases.

Comment: does your local server/application use a rewrite engine of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your local web server is serving the file up as text/css and the external one is not. What happens if you use TYPE="text/css" inside your LINK tag to the CSS file? That should force it to interpret the linked file as text/css.

Comment: it couldnt be that coz type can now be ommitted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364728/do-i-still-need-to-include-type-value-in-html5 it should have the same result whether there is one or not - unless the browser does not support html5

Comment: I specified "text/css" in both cases.