# ajax client-to-server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

**part a)** I m trying to send the value stored in the variable 'mem_ID' from my javascript page...default.aspx to my server side - default.aspx.cs page. But I keep getting an error message.

```
$.ajax({ 

        type: "POST", 
        url: "default.aspx.cs",
        data: "{mem_ID : ' " + mem_ID + "'}",
        async: true,
        // success: function (result) { } 
        });
```

$ - is undefined.
Expected identifier or string.

**part b) Also once i send this to the server side, how do i receive the value stored in the mem_ID ??**

Comment: @Philosophia....try using jQuery.ajax instead of the $.ajax. The $ sign is an alias for jQuery. Also, have you downloaded the latest jQuery library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`PageMethod`](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). Let's take an example of such a method in your code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod(string memId)
{
    return string.Format("Thanks for calling me with id: " + memId);
}
```

Things to note: the method must be static and decorated with the [`[WebMethod]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) attribute.

And on the client side you could invoke this method using the `jQuery.ajax()` function like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'default.aspx/MyMethod',
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ memID : mem_ID }),
    success: function (result) { 
        alert(result.d);
    } 
});
```

Also the error you are getting about the undefined `$` symbol is related to the fact that you didn't reference the jQuery library in your page. So make sure that in your WebForm you have actually added reference to the jQuery library before using it. For example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'WebMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Shift+Alt+F10+Enter while hovering over the `[WebMethod]` attribute will add the correct using directive to the top of your code behind: `using System.Web.Services;`. Also make sure that the `System.Web.Services.dll` assembly is referenced in your project. Please read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx

Comment: "type" attribute on your script tag?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, that's no longer necessary with HTML5. But I have added it for people still using HTML 4. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195441/29407

Comment: awesome! 

Error 2 'string' does not contain a definition for 'format'

Comment: Dude, that was a typo on my side, it should be `string.Format` with capital `F`. I have updated my answer. I guess you should take some basic C# getting started tutorial as those are some really, really basic things you should learn before even getting into ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks dude, indeed, working on some basic C# lessons. thanks for ur help

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, where did you see in my answer those global events that you are referring to in your comment?

Comment: @MarkSchultheissm sorry but that's a completely off-topic. The question here is how to call an ASP.NET Page Method with jQuery. If we start discussing the breaking changes in jQuery 1.9 I am afraid that we are going way off-topic.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I m having problems getting the return response from the server side. I don't think my ajax functionality is being invoked. could you take another look? I would appreciate it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697281/ajax-client-server-communication