# Sweetalert2 in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug, sweetalert2

I'm new to javascript/jade. I'm attempting to create a simple example using [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) from within a jade template file. When I run the following I receive the 'Help Me' alert but when I get to the **swal** line I receive:

ReferenceError: swal is not defined

```
html  
  head
    title= title
    style.
      body {
        font-family: verdanna;
        font-size: 19px;
        background: #aaaaaa;
      }
    link(type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='file:///home/dave/css/sweetalert2.css')
  body
    script(src='file:///home/dave/js/sweetalert2.min.js')
    script.
      var func=function() {
        alert('Help me');
        swal('swal help');
    block content
      h2 Hello
      button(onclick='func()') Alert
  footer
    .row
      .col-xs-12
        small © Neo Inc 2017
```

It should be noted that I'm running this from within an express/node.js based toy application. I've verified that the sweetalert2.css and sweetalert2.min.js files exist by copying the locations from the code and inserting them into another tab on the browser. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't include files with an absolute `file:///...` link in modern browsers from sites that are served with the HTTP protocol ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357)). You need to [specify a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734796), e.g. `src='../myPage.js'`. That path should be relative to the directory the HTML/Pug file is located in.

Comment: I modified the script line as follows:
<pre>
script(src='../js/sweetalert2.min.js')
</pre>
And in my firebug console output I now receive:
"Network Error: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3017/js/sweetalert2.min.js"
My app is running on port 3017

Comment: You need to serve that `js` folder as well ([quite straightforward](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) in Node express). The problem is that you're mix-and-matching files served from your file system and files served from your Node.js server - they need to be served by only _one_ of those two

Comment: That was it! I appreciate the answer and the references...thanks!