# AJAX, JQuery, JQuery UI, Stylesheet, Custom JS -- NOT LOADING ALL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading

Why is it that when I remove //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js the site runs my AJAX requests. Though when I have it, I cannot access the JQuery UI datePicker?

```
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src='js/custom.js'></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

Very bizarre - I posted the google api in a certain place that magically made it work. Anyone know why? 
I reposted by code here: [Why did this sequence of Jquery/Google API requests work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420812/why-did-this-sequence-of-jquery-requests-work)

Comment: you don't needed to import two jquery's. you can follow this: first import the `jquery.js` then import `custom.js` because i hope you  are doing ajax request in the `custom.js` and it need jquery

Comment: please see my answer. i have added comments, so that you may understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using two jquery and jquery ui. You must use one. since `.min.js` and `.js` are same. `min.js` is just the compressed version of `.js`

Ie the below code is enough:

```
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/nudgeme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/nudgeme.css">

<!-- First import jquery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<!-- Then Jquery library imports -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/nudgeme.js'></script>

<!-- Then Custom script that uses the above libraries-->
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/custom.js'></script> 
</head>
```

Use `custom.js` below all other `imports`. because javascript executed from top to bottom. so for example if your script uses a javascript function(for eg: jquery `$`) and you write the code above the import of `jquery.js` it simple won't work.

Comment: Thank you Suhail for the quick response. 
Though for some reason without the link ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js the ajax request will not load the received data. With it, the datePicker still will not load.

Comment: @user3250682 it is becuase you added line `<script type="text/javascript" src='js/custom.js'></script> ` above the line `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`. you just need to add it below `jquery.js`. that is it

Comment: I see what you mean, though the datePicker still refuses to show. Where would the google api fall into your provided code?

Comment: Very bizarre. No errors in the console. 
Seem to have made it work! I'll post what I did below - but if you know why please explain. I (as I'm sure other would) love to know why it worked...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420812/why-did-this-sequence-of-jquery-requests-work

Comment: @user3250682 because javascript code will executed from top to bottom. i mean it execute first line. then second line, then third......

Answer (score 1):

Ok i did not found `<!DOCTYPE html>`(so it is not html5) in your code and so i recommend you to mention type="text/javascript" in you script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

for reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags)

Comment: that is not necessary... :) i mean `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` is enough