# Does async do anything when injecting a <script> via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, script-tag

I was reading through [Which browsers support script async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async) which is discussing Google's script which looks like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxx']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

In the SO post, it states:

> The async support as specified by google is achieved using two parts:
>
> using script on your page (the script is supplied by google) to write
>   out a `<script>` tag to the DOM.
>
> that script has `async="true"` attribute to signal to compatible
>   browsers that it can continue rendering the page.
>
> The first part works on browsers without support for `<script async..`
>   tags, allowing them to load async with a "hack" (although a pretty
>   solid one), and also allows rendering the page without waiting for
>   ga.js to be retrieved.
>
> The second part only affects compatible browsers that understand the
>   `async` html attribute

This has me confused. What is the async attribute doing on the script above if they're already using another 'hack' to provide async support for browsers which do not respect the async: true attribute? Doesn't that hack work for all browsers?

Comment: Is `type` even recommended any more? I would say not

Comment: @danwellman: Yes, it is. What you might remember to be deprecated is `language`.

Comment: Nope. `type` has also been deprecated since HTML5. See this SO question, which was answered *4* years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags