# Is script type text/javascript required for IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm debugging Javascript issue on IE8, and I want to make sure that the problem is not because of this. I can't quite tell if the problem is because of this or because of something else. I search on the whole internet, but I feel it's very hard to get a very straightforward answer on this. Even w3school (people said that it's unreliable) that usually has "which browser support what feature starting from what version" is removing that information for this script tag. I understand there's many similar question on stack overflow that asking if it is okay to omit type attribute on script in general, and the usual answer is yes. But the client decided that the website must support IE8 too, and that's why I just need a straightforward answer:

Can I omit type attribute on script tag, on IE8?

If I omit it, will it has a problem, like raising Javascript error box, code not run properly, or anything, on IE8?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not required anywhere. It should work unless you do specify the attribute and choose an incorrect value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the 'type' attribute necessary for <script> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags)

Comment: @Jeremy, From another post, it says it is required in HTML 4, which includes IE 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags  However, I think most browsers will default to javascript as long as the file is not `.xhtml`.

Comment: It may be required by a specification, but the w3c's specs have never tracked well with reality.

Comment: @ps2goat yes, that's what I meant. they only talks about HTML 4 specs, not whether if IE8 (which is indeed running HTML 4 specs) is affected by it or not. But worry not, there's a solution already. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type attribute is optional if you use HTML5 and pass the proper doctype

```
<!doctype html>
```

Unfortunately, IE8 doesn't recognize this doctype so in theory it should require the type attribute specified. Fortunately, no one follows that particular standard, so running this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert('It works!');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

results in working JS under IE8, which means you don't really need the type attribute specified after all. Hope that helps.

Comment: In practice, I don't think the type attribute has been necessary for a very long time, even if strictly required for conformance with HTML 4. It was necessary in at least one very rare case, in early versions of IE where VBScript had been used previously in the page. But don't quote me on that. ;-)

Comment: Also, the type attribute can be used to target specified version of JS like: <script type="application/javascript;version=1.8"></script> which will run the script only if browser supports JS 1.8

Comment: Thanks! Now I can rest my worry about whether if all these errors are produced because of the type attribute is not present or not, as I can't change that unfortunately. Many questions and answers are only talking around HTML 4 specs but never talking directly about whether IE8 (which is using HTML 4 specs) requires it or not. Don't worry, I only curious for the IE8 only, not the earlier version than that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @metal03326—do you have a reference for that? The type (if present) must be [*a valid MIME type*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type). Adding version information seems to prevent the script from executing in any browser other than Firefox (probably because the MIME type is not recognised), so this would appear to be a proprietary extension available only in Mozilla browsers.

Comment: @RobG Firefox apparently supports this, don't know about other browsers [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: @FlyDanoFly—support has been removed from Firefox 59 so not even Firefox supports it. Strictly, JavaScript™ belongs to Mozilla, so no one else can claim to support a particular version without a significant effort to reverse engineer each version since there is no JavaScript™ specification. There is ECMA-262 and the various HTML and DOM standards, but they aren't JavaScript. MDN is a public wiki, and focuses on "javascript" implementations, not JavaScript™ *per se* so it's not a specification.