# html <select> onchange not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:

```
                  <select id="fontType">
                    <option value="Arial" style="font-family: Arial">Arial</option>
                    <option value="Courier New" style="font-family: Courier New">Courier New</option>
                    <option value="Georgia" style="font-family: Georgia">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="Tahoma" style="font-family: Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                    <option value="Times New Roman" style="font-family: Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                    <option value="Trebuchet MS" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
                    <option value="Verdana" style="font-family: Verdana">Verdana</option>
                  </select>
```

I want to read out what is written in the option, but onchange is not working:

```
                      <script>
                      document.getElementById("fontType").onchange = function(event) {
                          alert("Changed!");
                      };
                      </scrit>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much,

Lucas!

Comment: You've misspelt the word `script`.

Comment: potentially because you need to specify `<script type="text/javascript">`? Also your closing script tag is misspelled, but here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h86wkL7a/) for proof of concept.

Comment: @ShamSUP: The preferred way is `<script>`.

Comment: For further reference about the `<script>` tag: "[if the 'type'] attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript." - [script @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type). Also see [Is the 'type' attribute necessary for <script> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags/4195441)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I wrote `<scrit>` instead of `<script>`!

Comment: It seems to me that this *is* the answer.

Comment: There is a specific close reason for typos, so the question should be closed / deleted instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside window onload, seems like You declare js code before outputting html element.

```html
<script> 
   window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("fontType").onchange = function(event) {
       alert("Changed!");
     };
   }
</script>

<select id="fontType">
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
</select>
```