# Generate new unique name and id in table row as the form loads

Tags: jquery, html-table, attributes, row

```
<table border="1" id="matt">
<tr> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtLink" name="txtLink"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
     <td><input type="text"></td> 
     <td><input type="text"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
     <td><input type="text"></td> 
     <td><input type="text"></td> 
</tr>
```

```
<script language="javascript">
var i = 1;
$(window).load(function() {
$("tbody tr:last").find("input").each(function() {
$(this).attr({
  'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
  'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
  'value': ''               
});
}).end().appendTo("#matt");
i++;
});
</script>
```

given this code.. I want to generate and copy the attributes/tag from the first row of the table as the form loads, it should be unique..any help? I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Why do you need id's on these seemingly non-unique elements?

Comment: you can ignore the id..the important is the name because i'll be using it as basis in fetching the value to save it to database..

Comment: You need to first get the name of the elements in the first row, then iterate through them all using that name. Your current code will only properly set the name of the first, the rest will be named 1-n

Comment: only one subsidiary tip: instead of the deprecated attribute language="javascript" use standard one type="text/javascript" ([info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626563/leaving-out-type-text-javascript-language-javascript#2626573))

Comment: thanks for your immediate response...however, i'm not that good with this..would you mind sharing a code snippet of your idea, that will serve as my guide.

Comment: What is the purpose of `:last` in your code? ( i have to understand the code to fix it. )

Comment: the last row of the table..

Comment: It is unclear what is your aim: to add a new row at the end of the table, or only add modified attributes from the first row to each existing row? example: http://jsfiddle.net/aVpBR/

Comment: Your current code takes the last row and finds its inputs, iterates over them (just the inputs in that one row) and sets their name and id to "1". That obviously isn't what you want, what do you want it to do? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: the later part..i want to add modified attributes, supposedly the first row has the name element e.g. '<input name="at1"/>'..the second row should have '<input name="at2" />'

Comment: Thanks to @Stano..I may able to solve this. i'll go back if i get trouble again..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in case you only want **to copy those modified attributes** from the first table row's input tags to inputs in all other rows of the table, you can use this algorithm:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = $("table tbody tr");
    var txtTitle = rows.first().find('input').eq(0);
    var txtLink = rows.first().find('input').eq(1);
    rows.each(function (i) {
        if (i==0) { return; } // skip first row.
        var inputs = $(this).find('input');
        inputs.eq(0).attr('id', txtTitle.attr('id')+i )
            .attr('name', txtTitle.attr('name')+i )
            .attr('value', txtTitle.attr('value')+i );
        inputs.eq(1).attr('id', txtLink.attr('id')+i )
            .attr('name', txtLink.attr('name')+i )
            .attr('value', txtLink.attr('value')+i );
    });
});
```

The above code was tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVpBR/), its simplified version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVpBR/1/).

Also cloning a row in jQuery is as simple as e.g.:

```js
$('table#matt tbody').append($('table#matt tbody tr:first').clone());
```

Comment: thanks! one more..i just want it to copy only from the table id='matt'

Comment: Glad it helped :-) And well then just change the selector to `var rows = $("#matt tbody tr");`

Comment: that's what I thought...thanks...million thanks..i'll be able to save values to my sql database now..