# Linking in jQuery Makes Other Script Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still new to script, this my be a simple question.

On the site I am building right now I have some small script functions that work great, but when I linked in jQuery for a different function the first ones stopped working. If I remove the jQuery link they work again.

Here is the functions that I have currently:

This one is the one I need jQuery for, `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~ Header Background image rotation ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
$(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('.mainheader');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(img/rainbow.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/chicks_on_grass.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/cattle_on_pasture.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/csa_bundle.jpg)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 10000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

This next function still works normally

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~ ShowOrHide Element Onclick ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
function showOrHide(zap) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
  if (abra.display == "block") {
   abra.display = "none";
   } else {
   abra.display = "block";
  } 
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

This one does not work any more

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~ Form Email Hint ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
JotForm.init(function(){
  $('input_4').hint('ex: myname@example.com');
});
```

All three of these functions are enclosed in `<script language="JavaScript"></script>` tag.

Then I have a third party JavaScript link that controls some things on a form that I have on the site. `<script src="http://max.jotfor.ms/min/g=jotform?3.1.1667" type="text/javascript"></script>` This does not work alongside the JQuery either.

I have no idea what is going on, spent all day working on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: debug it! then tell us

Comment: Does your jotform script require a newer version of jQuery?

Comment: @ntgCleaner `1.11.0` is the newest stable release of the `1.x` branch...

Comment: I am not sure which Version it needs. Just thought newer would be better.

Comment: `language="JavaScript"` is deprecated...

Comment: No error messages come up, things just don't work.

Comment: @War10ck, Oh yeah! sorry, I have been experimenting with 2.1.0.  Sorry!

Comment: @War10ck not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @CWDesign No errors in your console? What is the script supposed to do? and what does it not do?  And it means it's not supported or there's something better than that to use :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626563/leaving-out-type-text-javascript-language-javascript

Comment: @CWDesign My apologies. The `language="javascript"` attribute should not be used and is deprecated in favor of `type="text/javascript"`. However, if you're validating against HTML5 both attributes can be omitted. Omitting both attributes when using XHTML 1.0 or HTML 4.01 is invalid however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conflict issue, refer to this page for further [documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)
do this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// ~~~~~~~~~~ Header Background image rotation ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
$j(document).ready(function(){
var header = $j('.mainheader');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(img/rainbow.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/chicks_on_grass.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/cattle_on_pasture.jpg)'
  , 'url(img/csa_bundle.jpg)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 10000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});

// ~~~~~~~~~~ ShowOrHide Element Onclick ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
function showOrHide(zap) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
  if (abra.display == "block") {
   abra.display = "none";
   } else {
   abra.display = "block";
  } 
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this, now the "Background Image Rotation" does not work but the rest does.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had missed a small change that you had made. Seems to work now.

Comment: great! If you find this answer useful please consider upvoting and marking as accepted answer so it remains useful for other people users with similar issues. thanks!