# Jquery not working inside of .net project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have this script referenced inside my main.master file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and inside of my Web User Control I have this jquery but it isnt working, i cant really see where there would be a problem. My code works just fine inside of jsfiddle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".package-container").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

My jquery is referenced near the bottom of my master page above the closing body tag.

Comment: wrap your code within `$(function(){ //your code });`

Comment: If you code is not at the end of the body, you need to wrap it in a DOM ready event

Comment: can you provide place where include jquery in master page?

Comment: move yout jquery reference in head tag

Comment: can you provide your **main.master**?

Comment: also, can you explain how _it isn't working_? error in console or not handle click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your jQuery include is placed early on the page (HEAD element) and either place your code at the end of the body element or wrap it in a DOM ready handler like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".package-container").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
        });
    });
</script>
```

`$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

The advantage of using DOM ready handlers, is that you can place the jQuery code anywhere (including injection by child views/controls).

**Update:**

If you also need to locally scope your `$` variable, I suggest using this rather nice shortcut DOM ready handler. It passes the jQuery instance as a first parameter to the DOM ready function you provide:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // Your code placed here can use $ without any worry about other packages!
});
```

Comment: Also, `type="text/javascript"` is an optional attribute of the `<script>` tag. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2706364/690573)

Comment: @Nathan Jones: Handy links, but I had read that HTML 4 required the `type` attribute for it to be *valid* HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626563/leaving-out-type-text-javascript-language-javascript