# Why write <script type="text/javascript"> when the mime type is set by the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mime-types

My understanding is that mime types are set by the web server. Why do we add the `type="text/javascript` or `type="text/css"` attribute? Isn't this a useless and ignored attribute?

Comment: Servers are rarely properly configured.

Comment: Also because you can put any type there, and if the browser is able to understand that type, it will execute the script.

Comment: @Gumbo: Really? Do you have some proof (i.e., some text containing statistics) for this?

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script/189877#189877

Comment: @Gumbo not surprising, given that browsers are historically lenient. [Maybe they shouldn't have been?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152533)

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: I've just noticed my own server fails setting the proper MIME-type for ".js" files. So there, now at least one case reported for a proof. OTOH, that "rarely" in Gumbo's original statement is overly pessimistic: I'm going to fix my crap right now, so the quest will still be left open again soon... ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[Douglas Crockford says](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html):

> `type="text/javascript"`
>
> This attribute is optional. Since
>   Netscape 2, the default programming
>   language in all browsers has been
>   JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute
>   is required and unnecessary. In HTML,
>   it is better to leave it out. The
>   browser knows what to do.

[He also says:](http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html)

> W3C did not adopt the `language`
>   attribute, favoring instead a `type`
>   attribute which takes a MIME type.
>   Unfortunately, the MIME type was not
>   standardized, so it is sometimes
>   `"text/javascript"` or
>   `"application/ecmascript"` or something
>   else. Fortunately, all browsers will
>   always choose JavaScript as the
>   default programming language, so it is
>   always best to simply write `<script>`.
>   It is smallest, and it works on the
>   most browsers.

For entertainment purposes only, I tried out the following five scripts

```
  <script type="application/ecmascript">alert("1");</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert("2");</script>
  <script type="baloney">alert("3");</script>
  <script type="">alert("4");</script>
  <script >alert("5");</script>
```

On Chrome, all but script 3 (`type="baloney"`) worked.  IE8 did not run script 1 (`type="application/ecmascript"`) or script 3.  Based on my non-extensive sample of two browsers, it looks like you can safely ignore the `type` attribute, but that it you use it you better use a legal (browser dependent) value.

Comment: That's not conform the HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT

Comment: Regarding the second part: read more about MIME types in RFC 4329: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt In fact, you really should specify `type="text/javascript"`, though many servers will send the file with Content-type: `application/javascript`.

Comment: I really wonder what IE 6 will do with these examples. And yes, at least the 5th one (with `type` omitted) will work in that browser. That's because most browsers have fallback settings included, in case a document doesn't conform to the standards; that's no excuse to serve non-standard things or even tag soup.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, thanks for the links to the standards docs.  I'm confused (or possibly not reading carefully): doesn't  ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt say *This document thus defines `text/javascript` and `text/ecmascript` but marks them as "obsolete"*

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, IE6 accepts the same scripts as IE8, according to IETester.

Comment: I was confused about this, too, the first time I saw it. It's just that the RFC people in their utter wisdom decided to standardize `application/javascript` in favour of `text/javascript`, but the former will just not work in some browsers (at least not in IE). Recently there was a discussion on the WHATWG mailing list about the default setting of `type` in HTML 5 vs. RFC 4329: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-April/025813.html (also read the rest of the thread).

Comment: @Marcel: I tested it in IE6, and only the `type=baloney` worked :)

Comment: @Daniel: Nice to know. :) From now on I will use `<!--[if IE 6]><script type=baloney>/* some evil crash code */</script><![endif]-->` on my pages. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_matter_how_thin_you_slice_it,_it%27s_still_baloney

Comment: Whai is it 'better' to leave out `type="text/javascript"` in HTML?

Answer (score 28):

Because, at least in HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1(.1), the `type` attribute for `<script>` elements is [required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT).

In [HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#script), `type` is no longer required.

In fact, while you should use `text/javascript` in your HTML source, many servers will send the file with `Content-type: application/javascript`. Read more about these MIME types in [RFC 4329](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt).

Notice the difference between RFC 4329, that marked `text/javascript` as obsolete and recommending the use of `application/javascript`, and the reality in which some browsers freak out on `<script>` elements containing `type="application/javascript"` (in HTML source, not the HTTP Content-type header of the file that gets send). Recently, there was a discussion on the WHATWG mailing list about this discrepancy (HTML 5's `type` defaults to `text/javascript`), read these messages with subject [Will you consider about RFC 4329?](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-April/thread.html#25810)

Answer (score 13):

Boris Zbarsky (Mozilla), who probably knows more about the innards of Gecko than anyone else, provided at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Apr/0195.html the pseudocode repeated below to describe what Gecko based browsers do:

```
if (@type not set or empty) {
   if (@language not set or empty) {
     // Treat as default script language; what this is depends on the
     // content-script-type HTTP header or equivalent META tag
   } else {
     if (@language is one of "javascript", "livescript", "mocha",
                             "javascript1.0", "javascript1.1",
                             "javascript1.2", "javascript1.3",
                             "javascript1.4", "javascript1.5",
                             "javascript1.6", "javascript1.7",
                             "javascript1.8") {
       // Treat as javascript
     } else {
       // Treat as unknown script language; do not execute
     }
   }
} else {
   if (@type is one of "text/javascript", "text/ecmascript",
                       "application/javascript",
                       "application/ecmascript",
                       "application/x-javascript") {
     // Treat as javascript
   } else {
     // Treat as specified (e.g. if pyxpcom is installed and
     // python script is allowed in this context and the type
     // is one that the python runtime claims to handle, use that).
     // If we don't have a runtime for this type, do not execute.
   }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, please note that the use of the `language` attribute is deprecated: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-language

Answer (score 6):

It allows browsers to determine if they can handle the scripting/style language before making a request for the script or stylesheet (or, in the case of embedded script/style, identify which language is being used).

This would be much more important if there had been more competition among languages in browser space, but VBScript never made it beyond IE and PerlScript never made it beyond an IE specific plugin while JSSS was pretty rubbish to begin with.

The draft of HTML5 makes the attribute optional.