# JavaScript content-type

Tags: javascript, apache2, content-type

When I add JavaScript files to web pages, I have always done for example like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Custom script
</script>
```

But today I discovered in the response headers that JavaScript are actually served as `application/javascript`. Why is that? Is both correct? Or should I change one to the other? What's going on here?

Comment: I think that this one explains it good: http://annevankesteren.nl/2006/05/javascript-mime-type

Comment: Also see [Why write <script type=“text/javascript”> when the mime type is set by the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-typetext-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-server)

Comment: Well, it explained that application/javascript was the one I should use. But not which one I *should* use... Also its from 2006. So is it still the case that I should use text/javascript because of browsers, or?

Comment: @Svish: At least IE 7 (and 8?) does have problems with `script` elements with MIME-type set to `application/javascript`, and as there are still plenty IE users out there…

Comment: Well, link appears to be broken. Good answer should link to original sources, but also refer most important contents briefly - just because this happens all the time.

Comment: Link is not broken, check your connection and remove that -1 as it's not constructive.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed. Include the relevant details in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

with HTML5, you can just omit the type attribute completely.  All browsers assume a default type of JavaScript.