# Do I still need to use type='text/javascript'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why write <script type=“text/javascript”> when the mime type is set by the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve)

I know that `<script type='type/javascript'></script>` does not need the type attribute anymore. My question is, when inserting scripts myself, do I still need to use it?

```
var hello = document.createElement('script');
hello.type = 'text/javascript'; // still needed?
hello.async = true;
hello.src = 'http://mysite.com/script.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(hello);
```

I see that in Google Analytics they still use it `ga.type = 'text/javascript';` and Disqus use it as well with `dsq.type = 'text/javascript';`

So, is this needed?

Comment: AFAIK, as of HTML5, it's no longer required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why write <script type="text/javascript"> when the mime type is set by the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239032/do-you-really-need-to-specify-the-type-attribute

Comment: you mean the `type` (`type="text/javascript"`) not the `src`, that's needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is the default value, if the attribute is absent:

From the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type):

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME
>   type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which
>   is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Comment: Note that that is the HTML5 specification. Please clarify which was the first version to specify such a default.