# How to use the minify and GZip Compressed file?

Tags: jquery, html, css, gzip

I have Compressed & Gzipped my style and js files using this [site](http://www.zbugs.com/minify-gzip-compress-css-javascript-online) Now I have files with name `style.min.css` and `jquery.min.js` respectively. Let me know how can I link these files to reduce the page load?

Comment: just include them in your html pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set the content encoding for those files to gzip for the browser to read it correctly, try this in your .htaccess file

```
<filesMatch "\.min\.(js|css)$">
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: @user1012181 make sure you are allowed to set headers in your .htaccess file

Comment: @user1012181 you need to have `AllowOverride` set to `FileInfo` or `All` in http.conf for the directory you have the .htaccess file in

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines inside your head tag.

```
<link href="style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `<script>` should have the attribute `type="text/javascript"`. And `<link>` should have `type="text/css"` too.

Comment: Any other things to be included in the `htaccess` file?

Comment: @user1012181 You shouldn't add anything in the `.htaccess` file, except if you want to redirect *style.css* to *style.min.css*. But instead of redirections, you should change the links.

Comment: @Oriol I don't think the html5 doctype requires that. Here is further information from previous [stackoverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239032/do-you-really-need-to-specify-the-type-attribute)

Comment: @user1012181 Add more information then. We can only assume your problems if you don't attach information other than it doesn't work.

Comment: When I reloaded my page after changing the linking as per your answer, the browser isn't reading the css or js file at all....