# HTML do I need a mime type for the link tag?

Tags: html, hyperlink, mime-types

David crockford recommends ommitting the `type="application/javascript"` attribute for the script tag. Should I do the same for a CSS link tag (omit `"type=text/css"`)? I googled "html link omit mime type" and some variants and didn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per documentation for [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Now, let's take a look at [`<link>`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/link#HTML_Attributes):

> The default value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/css".

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) is not clear on this for some reason, but it does contain this:

> Since that default type is text/css...

The `type` attribute is also purely advisory.  Modern browsers definitely don't need it if it's valid CSS.

Comment: Ah thanks, actual w3 reference... I never use it enough. In this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve, it says "in xhtml, [the script tag mime type attribute] is required and uncessary". Is it it "required but unnecessary" for the link tag too? Good practice to include or exclude it?

Comment: @Raekye HTML5 (really it should just called be "HTML" at this point) doesn't have *any* required attributes as far as I know.  XHTML is dead (at this point)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that either. But erm, it's optional, but would you say to include it or not? Why so? Like I'd guess I should include the rel tag (the browser can figure out what the mime type is from the server, and can only guess what the rel tag should be)

Comment: @Raekye - [XHTML5 is live and kicking.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml). Crockford's information is out of date; the type attribute is not required in XHTML5.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - There's a better line in the spec about the default type. Under [4.12.5.11 Link type "stylesheet"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#link-type-stylesheet) it says "The default type for resources given by the stylesheet keyword is text/css.". That's opposed to the icon link type where it says "There is no default type for resources given by the icon keyword. However, for the purposes of determining the type of the resource, user agents must expect the resource to be an image."

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical reason to use the `type` attribute in either `script` or `link` elements, when you are using JavaScript and CSS, as you are (almost always). However, if there is an external requirement imposed upon you to conform to the HTML 4.01 specification, use `type="text/javascript"` in `script`, and double-check that you enter it correctly.

Those attributes are never needed (for JavaScript and CSS), but they hurt you if you misspell them. Then browsers will expect that your script is in `text/javascript` or your style sheet is in `text/ccs` and ignore it, since they do not know such languages.

In a `script` element, you would need a `type` attribute only if the content is *not* to be interpreted as JavaScript but e.g. as VBScript or not interpreted at all, just stored as data.