# Jquery file inclusion issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Developing ASP.NET application with visual studio 2010

I am new with jquery.

I am trying to include JQuery file online (from google)

For this i have written it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here it is highlighting src attribute with green text showing tool tip that:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js not found.
```

If i write it as:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It shows me error as a tooptip that:

```
Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'
```

But this is the actual way in which i refered this line on different sites.

I have refered this addess from different sites.

Is this address is wrong? or

I have written it in wrong way?

please help me.

Comment: Your editor might be stuck on HTML4. In HTML5 it's not required.

Comment: using visual studio 2010

Comment: Can't help you there, I've no idea of VS. Not a big fan of linting as you type tho... I prefer static analysis tools, such as the official W3 validator.

Comment: @elclanrs fine. Thanks for giving time on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol-less paths inherit the protocol of the current document when opened in a browser, so this will work when your page is opened through `http`/`https` protocols.

Therefore I assume that your VS interprets the protocol-less path as a local one, thus it is not found.

You can check that the CDN URL is correct by opening the link directly through either http/https protocols:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js

---

As for the `type` attribute, see [Why write `<script type=“text/javascript”>` when the mime type is set by the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve)

In sum, all browsers since Netscape 2 default script tags to `javascript`, so as long as the server sends the correct MIME it will work just fine. However, it wouldn't validate under W3C's HTML4 mode. In HTML5, it is valid to omit the `type` attribute as commented by @elclanrs.

Comment: Thanks. This covers all of my daubts

Comment: sir, but how script runs here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_ready without type='javascript' and not on my side?

Comment: It's worth to read about `<script>` tag by [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html).

Comment: @Freelancer The HTML on the left is put inside an `iframe` (to the right) which is ran through `http` (just as if you were opening a page with that HTML). +1 Nox, though a little dated it is still a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

```
use it like this. it works

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```