# jQuery ready function not working, it never runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery, but the `ready` function doesn't seem to work:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="locationdemo">
      <p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
      <button id="locationButton" onclick="getLocation()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" clas="load">
      <p>Acquiring Location</p>
      <img border="0" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" width="32" height="16">
    </div>
```

Script begins here;

```
<script src="Distance.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("why isn't this running?");
    $("#loading").hide();
  });
  var x=document.getElementById("demo");
  var retries = 0;
  function getLocation() {
    alert("before check");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      var timeoutVal = 6000;//in milliseconds
      var watchid = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        displayPosition,
        displayError,
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
      );
    } else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
  function displayPosition(position) {
    var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
    var maxAcceptableAccuracy = 300.48//in meters, this is eqaul to 100 feet
    alert("accuracy: "+accuracy);
    if(accuracy > maxAcceptableAccuracy && retries < 10) {
      retries = retries++;
      getLocation();
      return;
    }
    retires = 0;
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
  function displayError(error) {
    var errors = {
      1: 'Permission denied',
      2: 'Position unavailable',
      3: 'Request timeout'
    };
    alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The alert("why isn't this running"); is not running. What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck on this for 2 hours.

Comment: Are you trying with file:// or in a localhost server?

Comment: did you tell your browser to ignore more popups from this page?

Comment: You should specify 'http://' in the url for `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: If running with `file://`, the `src=//` will fail.

Comment: To all who think the `http:` part in the `src` is needed: It's not uncommon to omit the scheme so that the files can be served without problem from `http` as well as `https`. The scheme is filled automatically. As Raphael mentioned, if the HTML file is served differently (e.g. via `file`), this won't work though.

Comment: Side note: there's a typo in `retires = 0;` That will affect your code at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the location to point to correct CDN and have your distance.js script file import after jQuery is loaded

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Distance.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("why isn't this running?");
        $("#loading").hide();

    });


    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    var retries = 0;

    function getLocation()
    {
      alert("before check");


        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
              var timeoutVal = 6000;//in milliseconds
              var watchid = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                displayPosition, 
                displayError,
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
              );
        }

      else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }  
    function displayPosition(position)
    {
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var maxAcceptableAccuracy = 300.48//in meters, this is eqaul to 100 feet
        alert("accuracy: "+accuracy);
        if(accuracy > maxAcceptableAccuracy && retries < 10)
        {
            retries = retries++;
            getLocation();
            return;

        }
        retires = 0;
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    }

    function displayError(error) {
      var errors = { 
        1: 'Permission denied',
        2: 'Position unavailable',
        3: 'Request timeout'
      };
    alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, didn't realize i needed http: before //

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("why isn't this running?");
            $("#loading").hide();

        });

    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    var retries = 0;

    function getLocation()
    {
      alert("before check");


        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
              var timeoutVal = 6000;//in milliseconds
              var watchid = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                displayPosition, 
                displayError,
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
              );
        }

      else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }  
    function displayPosition(position)
    {
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var maxAcceptableAccuracy = 300.48//in meters, this is eqaul to 100 feet
        alert("accuracy: "+accuracy);
        if(accuracy > maxAcceptableAccuracy && retries < 10)
        {
            retries = retries++;
            getLocation();
            return;

        }
        retires = 0;
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    }

    function displayError(error) {
      var errors = { 
        1: 'Permission denied',
        2: 'Position unavailable',
        3: 'Request timeout'
      };
    alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't help much when you copy/paste the entire block of code (after reformatting) and change a single line... You should just point out what was wrong, what you fixed, and why.

Comment: @jahroy I creating my answer without the rest of a code and  I put the line <script type="text/javascript"> (look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve for why this script).
´var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    var retries = 0;´ until bottom.
After I copy the rest code on the question, paste in my AS.
Is stupid to do the down-vote on my AS

Comment: I'll remove my downvote, but I don't understand anything you just said.  My point was that you should mention what you changed and why.  Otherwise we have to read through both pieces of code carefully to find the changes (the fact that you changed all the formatting make it impossible to diff).