# alert in javascript not running

Tags: javascript

Well here's my Function as well as my basic HTML page. I have created it with an alert script but it does not run.

Here's the function (Something.js)

```
function crypto_encrypt(text) {                                                                        //This is for JS
var keyBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), keyBase64,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

// Returns a Base64 encoded string.
return encrypted;
}
```

Now I have this HTML but when i load it it does not give an alert
(Test.php) <-----does it have something to do with the naming when I saved it in sublime?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery.soap.js'></script>
<!--<script type='text/javascript' src='./soapclient.js'></script>-->

<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js">   </script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-   base64-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./HCSConnect.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
   var encryptedname = crypto_encrypt('Patrick'); 
   alert(encryptedname)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Uhmm....I don't know sir.....How do I check for that?>

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: alerts disbaled for your site?

Comment: missing `;` after alert statement and remove spaces from source URL.  Also,  [it's advisable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2706290/1369473) to use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: crypto_encrypt is not defined`

Comment: if you are using chrome or firefox press ctrl+shift+I to open the developer console, you should see a javascript console there and if there's an error you should be see it there

Answer (score 2):

There are some spaces in the url for this script:

```
http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-   base64-min.js
```

That is the reason you get a 404 (not found). The entire following script fails. Change it to:

```
http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qTrGf/).

Comment: @user15077: need more help?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` after `alert()` statement.

Remove spaces from source URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"
```

Also, [it is advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706290) to use type="text/javascript"