# What is difference between these two script code? are they totally different or can i use only one src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I got that one is for jquery and one is for ajax. but can i use only one to reduce network request?

Comment: You only need to include jQuery once. Why are you including two different versions?

Comment: So they are the same one even the looking of address is different. Thanks! I was confused if they are the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that one is loading jQuery 1.11.1 from jQuery and the other is loading jQuery 1.11.2 from Google.

You should absolutely only include one. The second one will override the first one anyway.