# Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. Something is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web.py

Somehow, the button is not defined, even though it is specified by the script. What's missing?

index.html

```
   $def with (form, text)
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Reverser</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <input id="str_invert_input" type="text">
                <button onclick="app.invert()">Invert</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <h2 id="result"></h2>
            </div>
            <script src="/web/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

main.js

```
var app = {
  invert : function(){
    var str = $('#str_invert_input');
    var inputVal = str.val();
    var encoded = encodeURI(inputVal);

    var result = $('#result');

    // Add the web service URL
    $.get( "http://127.0.0.1:8081/"+encoded, function( data ) {

    result.html(data);

    });
  }

}
```

As you can see the app seems to have been defined, and called by the script on the index.html.

main.py

```
import web
from web import form

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'index',
)

render = web.template.render('C:/Users/A/Desktop/Web/templates')

my_form = form.Form(
                form.Textbox('', class_='textfield', id='textfield'),
                )

class invert:
    def GET(self, invert):
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return render.index(form, "String Reverser!")
        #no code yet




app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```

Comment: you have 

`<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/html"></script>` 

when it should be:

`<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @Pabs123 Interesting, changing it makes the error now go into `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`  , and the app still remains not defined.

Comment: you need to do the same with the jQuery include

Comment: @Pabs123 same thing happened, but thanks!

Comment: sounds like a problem with your HTML syntax, try running it through a validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your `HTML` code and found that script `type` is wrong defined.

You have to Replace this

```
<script src="/web/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/html"></script>
<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/html"></script>
```

With the

```
<script src="/web/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Other thing is , i thought

`$def with (form, text)`

This code should be in script tag within the head section if it is related to Javascript/jquery..

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are including your files using the wrong type

```
<script src="/web/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/html"></script>
<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/html"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="/web/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/web/static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since you have them as `text/html`, the variables inside are not being recognized as such, and same goes with functions and other javascript objects. You will get all sorts of undefined behaviour because of this.

As an added note, it's not necessarily because you were missing `text/javascript` that the errors were occurring. If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve), it seems that the `type` attribute isn't fully necessary. The reason for your error is that you explicitly stated `text/html`, so the files will be treated in that way.