# Canvas maximization bug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, maximize

I must've killed over an hour on what seems to me like strange behaviour that happens in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Here is some code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Watch me grow scrollbars!</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="resizeCanvas()">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function resizeCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
    }
</script>
```

Basically, the canvas always seems to maximize 'too much', and the window grows scrollbars on both sides. I've tried using various ways of obtaining the document dimensions, including nesting canvas in a 100% wide & tall absolutely positioned div, as well as extracting the document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height properties.

Just to be sure I'm not going insane, I've placed an image in place of the canvas, and voila, the same code worked perfectly to stretch the image out to document dimensions.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm too tired to understand. Must.. drink.. something.

Comment: You probably also need to set the style for `body` and `canvas` elements with `margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0;`. But honestly, my quick test in Firefox still shows scrollbars.

Comment: Setting `display:block` for the canvas does the trick I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a workaround for the issue (still open to feedback) so for now I have hidden overflow on the parent container element which brought about roughly what I was looking for. Still, it can't be good if it's this inconsistent. Unless I'm missing something..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to extend the canvas to cover the whole page, the best solution I found is to let CSS automatically resize it to 100%, then use the current canvas element size to reset the canvas resolution.
In order to avoid having scrollbars you must also set the canvas CSS position to absolute.

*(tested with Chrome 34, Firefox 27, Explorer 11)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="resizeCanvas()" style="margin: 0;">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function resizeCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("width", canvas.offsetWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute("height", canvas.offsetHeight);

        // We draw a circle, just to test that it works
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(canvas.offsetWidth/2, canvas.offsetHeight/2, canvas.offsetHeight/2,    0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, this works in Firefox 4, but I haven't tried in other browsers because I don't have them in this computer.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Watch me grow scrollbars!</title>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            height = document.body.clientHeight,
            width = document.body.clientWidth;
        canvas.setAttribute("height", height);
        canvas.setAttribute("width", width);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(128,128,128)';
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, width-20, height-20);
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="resizeCanvas()">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

As for IE7 (which doesn't support canvas anyway), I had to change your script's type attribute from `application/javascript` to `text/javascript` to make the code work.

This is why: (quoting keparo on [What is the javascript MIME type for the type attribute of a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script))

> The MIME type for javascript wasn't
>   standardized for years. It's now
>   officially: "application/javascript".
>
> The real kicker here is that most
>   browsers won't use that attribute
>   anyway, at least not in the case of
>   the script tag. They actually peek
>   inside the packet and determine the
>   type for themselves.
>
> So the bottom line is that the
>   type="text/javascript" doesn't do
>   anything as far as the javascript is
>   concerned, but it's part of the spec
>   for both HTML 4 and XHTML 1.0.

I don't know if this still stands for more recent versions of IE.