# jQuery, IE 7 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, drupal

I'm including some lines of Javascript code in a Drupal page with input format as full html.
The script works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but IE (7) fails with

> 'Object doesn't support this property
>   or method'

this is the exact code I'm inserting in the Drupal page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/css/slimbox2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/jquery-1.6.1.js">
<script type="application/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/slimbox2.js">
<script type="application/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery("#pics").EmbedPicasaGallery('mygallery',{
    matcher: /./,
    loading_animation: 'css/loading.gif',
    msg_back :   'Back',
    size:      '85'
 });
});
</script>

<div id="pics" />
```

The javascript error occurrs on this line, at char 2:

```
jQuery("#pics").EmbedPicasaGallery('mygallery',{
```

This probably is not a very orthodox way of including a custom javascript in a Drupal page.
How should I do it, and how can I make it work with IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest transferring the `.noConflict()` call right after the `<script>` tag for jQuery, and switching `application/javascript` to `text/javascript` (though I'm not really sure about `application/javascript` --- just never used it before).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/jquery-1.6.1.js">
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/slimbox2.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/gallery/jquery-1.6.1/jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js">

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#pics').EmbedPicasaGallery({
        // blah
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, you may want to double check your `matcher` variable in the JSON object you pass in. I'm assuming that might be a string you're passing in, so you might have to pass that in as `matcher : '/./'`.

Comment: +1 Looks like a good call, check the first comment in the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script/189877#189877).

Comment: @Town ~ Thanks for the link! Must be why I've never used it before. frackin' 90% debugging for IE. With IE9 (and "improved" standards compatibility), I'll have to check this again then. +1

Comment: Problem was indeed <script type="application/javascript"> failing in Internet Explorer. I had to use <script type="text/javascript">