# Difference between application/javascript and text/javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading a tutorial on HTML 5 Canvas Animation with javascript (of course). In the header, the author used
`application/javascript` which is rather new to me because I've only seen `text/javascript` used. Can anyone help?
There is every likelihood this question has been asked before but I'm using a phone to do this so I can't see any similar questions.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Javascript MIME Type? What belongs in the type attribute of a script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script)

Comment: I don't know the difference but I know that HTML5 default value for `type` attribute on `script` element is `text/javascript` http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type

Comment: And someone could use also application/x-javascript. Anyway, the browsers are tolerant and it might no matter.

Comment: surprisingly all the answers are similar to this guy's answer :p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- text/javascript - is obsolete
- application/javascript - MIME type for JS

**Guidelines:**

- Use application/javascript on the server to return MIME type
- Use text/javascript for type attributes of `<script>` tag although it's not really required

Answer (score 2):

`application/javascript` is the correct MIME type for Javascript, although `text/javascript` shouldn't cause any issues