# Storing Additional Data in Script / Comment / Hidden Div

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Comming from the old school, I just ask myself where should I have to embedded additional  data for my JS code?

#### Comment tags

In the old times (2008) I used to store data within the comment block. I am quite suspicious now about this. I am quite unsure if one or more popular browsers remove comment tags on page load. Beside this insecurity, this always worked well. Especially one do not have to worry about tags etc unless --> is contained within the data.

#### Hidden Div

Another common technique I used in production was storing additonal information inside a hidden div. Also worked very well and using the hidden class / style of the div up front does not introduce fragments of this data being visible on load.

#### Script Tag

From reading the HTML5 specs I am quit certain that additional data should be stored inside the  tag. This also gives the chance to load huge amount of data using the src="" file and embed the data in javascript directly (Base64 Encoded strings etc). Also one might choose plain text format and write it directly within the script tag.

So considering all those options, what is the most common one? Can I use the src attribute for any data formats within the script tag? How does a server handles those?

Thanks for reading.

#### Update:

I need to store the data along the HTML page. This is about providing additional data to save Server/AJAX requests.

A good example is having a photo search site where one finds lets say 10k photos. Each photo has an ID. Since we have a small site we only have lets say a billion pictures. Using Base64 encoding we store each id with 5 bytes (6*5 = 30bit). Now we send 10k * 5 = 50KB of additional information embedded within the HTML page. Since we use compressed HTML those 50KB might be worth around 30KB so it is not a big problem.

From those IDs we can now generate the picture URI/URL links. And so when the user is scrolling the result list up and down the pictures are just requested and no additional roundtrip hits the server and the pictures are delivered utilizing the CDN.

Of cause I dont need this for pictures but the idea is similar.

Comment: You might also retrieve the additional data via ajax request - for example in json format.

Comment: If i understand you query correctly, you need SPA(Single-Page-Application) solution. Check javascriptMVC/backbone.js/Angular.js etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a bit .NET specific answer, sort of long winded and abstract, but hopefully you get the idea. Overall I store huge amount of data (when I can) in the output cache using the JavaScriptSerializer with aider serializers an object in C# into JSON or deserializers JSON into a C# object, with one line of code.

If you are into .NET you can find it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Now the beauty of this is that the data is fully in JSON format or in other words its fully ready to be used by JS. I usually simply store it in a global variable like `Data` (or something in those lines, its actually rarely a global variables in my case).

This means if I have a complex data structure in the server side I can simply call the same structure in the client side with no extra effort. Also when the structure changes (with happens a lot with me) then the JSON data structure is updated as well and I only need to think about how to handle the new data. Or basically maintaining the code becomes fairly painless. This also makes Server Side and Client Side communication easier and more flexible, but you really should try it out for your self to understand what I mean.

So basically my advise would be to store the data in JS inside a global variable in JSON format using some sort of Serializer, this makes both server side and client side programming easier and and more flexible with the minimal amount of effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end you generate inline JavaScript enclosed within a <script> tag. This is half the answer I need. What I am currently looking for is the mime type that the script tag needs to handle.

In the comment solution I was able to store everything I wanted. From javascript (Eval to execute it for instance) to binary data encrypted in base64.

Currently I need a way to store a list of 1000+ ids for caching a complete search result I only request information about certain entries when the user scrolls down and request more information.

Comment: In the end I just need to know if something like <script type="text/plain"> is sufficient and good html including supported by all browsers.

Comment: @MartinKersten Well, at least with the .NET serializer you can almost serialize anything you want. As for the mime type, well I've simply always used "text/javascript" without really thinking about it, but you can check this out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script. In your specific case I would make a object describing one SQL return line and store the search results in an array (1 obj per 1 SQL row), serialize the array and place it into the output cache. I could give you an example but only in C#.

Comment: @MartinKersten I have my reservations with `<script type="text/plain">` because the `script` tag is not really designed for storing text, but scripts. The browser could interpret it as faulty JS and throw and error. On a side note, most JS developers agree that `eval()` is evil.

Comment: @MartinKersten So the "text/plain" thing peeked by interest enough for me to try it out. In all browsers IE6+, FF, Chrome, Mac Safari, iOS Safari it worked as intended. I was able to store actual JS as text without it firing and was able to retrieve it without problems. So because this is actually valid HTML and not even older browsers try to be smart with it I would say go for it if that's what you need, I'd still would advise serializing though.

Comment: Thanks for trying out. I wondered when studying the specs whether there are limits for this.

Comment: No, this is standard HTML so you can place as much text as you please into it, but of course the only limit you need to keep in mind that you should not use </script> in your text or the tag will  close, but thats a given.

Comment: Thats why I will most likely use base64 or a derivate to store 2^30 in 5 characters. This will give me a good way to store bigger search results for infinity search only hitting the server for pictures rather then a research or query caching... . Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you try with window.localStorage... example:

```
    //basic function
    function session(v1,v2){
        if(typeof v2 == "undefined"){
            return window.localStorage.getItem(v1);
        } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem(v1, v2);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //example
    //save
    session("my.private.data", "someValue");
    //show
    alert(session("my.private.data"));
    //use
    var myvar = session("my.private.data");
```

Comment: As far as I got it this would store information on the device itself making it possible to not request those information when transitioning from one page to the other. What I need is to embedded data within the very same HTML page, thus allowing me to apply pagination / infinity scrolling without requesting additional information for the next information to fill those search result 'page(s)'.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set custom attributes on a div that's hidden.  See the following link:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

Comment: That was New to me thanks! But what I am looking for is a solution that can be used to store lets say an entire Json document or an XML. We used a comment for that, But I am unsure weather this is feaseble. one idea is using a hidden div as a replacement.

Comment: But the goal is utilizing the script Tag somehow.