# Chrome Error - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have tried ALL the solutions on many pages with no success.  I did not have Visual Studio installed so no registry tweaks needed there.  Adding in header tags into PHP did not work for me.  It seemed it was affecting my .css files and also my .js files.  Firefox would only show the .css errors and also show NO style rules at all.

**The exact errors are...**

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://newpcs.perrycs.com/css/bootstrap-theme-cerulean.css".

**and**

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://newpcs.perrycs.com/js/bootstrap.js".

**UPDATE:**
I found a fix from my web host IT.  They said to add the following code to my .htaccess file and it DID solve the .css but not the .js in Chrome.  Here is the code they had me put in...

```
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(\.css)$"> 
   AddType text/css .css 
   Header set Content-Type text/css 
</FilesMatch>

AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

It fixed it for the .css but not the .js

I have also tried...

```
AddType application/javascript .js
```

with no luck.  I"m waiting to hear back from IT again but in the meantime I'll keep looking.  I know the .js works.. it's just an OCD thing ... I don't want ANY errors in Chrome.

Comment: Nopes. I am getting `application/javascript` in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was waiting to get help from IT.  I previously asked them... should I do the same with the .js as with the .css and I was told NO... the only thing you need for .js is

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

That's what they gave me... and it did NOT solve my problem.  I also tried...

```
AddType application/javascript .js
```

and that did NOT work as well.

So... I thought I would try the thing I was told not to try.  Here is my final .htaccess file.

```
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(\.css)$"> 
   AddType text/css .css 
   Header set Content-Type text/css 
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "(\.js)$"> 
   AddType application/javascript .js
   Header set Content-Type application/javascript 
</FilesMatch>
```

and... it WORKS!  No more errors in Chrome.  I have no idea about .htaccess files... I thought... well, it didn't work with the .js after all... so what harm can come from this?  Anyone want to help me out and tell me that what I have done is a bad thing?  Any bad side effects?

I should also note... there was never a problem in the past with my .css files or my .js files.  It seems to have happened after they upgraded something but I do not know for sure as I wasn't looking into the problem right when I noticed my CSS styles disappeared from my side projects.  Well, as long as it works...

Comment: This should be fine. It just sets the headers in the right way. Nothing else, and this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try:

```
AddType application/javascript *.js
```

I feel that the `*` might help.

---

Might redeclaring the same thing of CSS for JS would help?

```
<FilesMatch "(\.js)$"> 
   AddType application/javascript .js
   Header set Content-Type application/javascript 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I tried it with and without the *.js and the same error popped up in Chrome.  Very weird problem.  In the past this is all I needed for the .js ... I don't know what they changed on the server.  One day all my CSS is working, and poof, next day all not working.

Comment: I know it has been depreciated but have you tried `Header set Content-Type text/javascript`

Comment: When I tried the header command (in PHP) my page only showed up as text... all the code was dumped directly to the webpage "as is".  I saw that help on another page.  Thx tho!

Comment: I'm curious WHY it doesn't work...  I know there is probably no way to tell without being on the server WHY I have to do the Files Match for the .js also!  Everything I have read says to JUST have what you guys have all said to put in.  Well, as long as it works... I'm happy.  This also seems to solve some other problems on some other questions that could never be resolved.  No-one could get rid of the .js error.  IT gave me the Files Match for the .css but told me to ONLY use the 1 line for .js.  Weird things...  so much to learn. Wish I was younger and had more time.  Getting old sucks.

Comment: @PerryCS There's a big set of type handler in Apache, which serves the default types. May be that file is screwed up or something!

Answer (score 1):

if the CSS rule works, you could replicate it for JavaScript:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.js)$"> 
   AddType application/javascript .js 
   Header set Content-Type application/javascript
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  The only reason I didn't try that was... I asked them...  and they said NO.  I didn't need to do that.  After typing this in as a question I thought.. what the heck... I'll do it anyways.  Why should it matter only doing on .css files and not .js files?  Server load?  I know nothing about .htaccess files.  My main one on my parent website is a mess.  I'll post that one.  Maybe the problem is in THAT .htaccess file.  Well, that is.. IF they are inherited?

Comment: THis is my MAIN .htaccess file on my parent website.  The newpcs.perrycs.com is a subdomain? website.  My original .htaccess file was never as messy as what it is now...

Comment: suPHP_ConfigPath /home/perrycs
RewriteEngine on
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home/perrycs
#Options ExecCGI Includes
#AddType application/x-httpd-CGI .pl
#AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .htm .html .shtml .js .css
Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Includes
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .xhtm .js .css .asp
AddHandler server-parsed .htm

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# mod_headers is not allowed. Use the following from perl where necessary
# P3P: CP="ALL DSP CURa ADMa OTPi OUR DELi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV STA"

Comment: continued... 

# P3P: policyref=\"http://www.perrycomputerservices.com/w3c/p3p.xml\"

#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perrycs\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perrycs\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.perrycomputerservices\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: I don't know why they would ask you to treat JavaScript files differently. However, they deserve kudos for giving you the [correct JavaScript MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script).

Comment: they actually had an x- in there.  I took it out after LOTS of reading about this problem trying to solve it with no success.  :)

Comment: is there supposed to be an -x? - oops... nm.. I just read the link you gave.  Its not supposed to have an -x :)

Answer (score -2):

Oh man, they are trolling you !!!
This is a very simple case, no alteration of .htaccess is needed.

Its about the file format. I dont mean the extension, but the way u created the file.

For example: If you get the error on a linux server, i bet you created that file inside of windows explorer or kinda.

The solution is to open the file in notepad++ and goto menu "coding".
No u have to know which charset is selected for your webserver.
They have to match (fileformat-serverformat)
Now u select "Convert into [yourformat]", for me its "UTF8 wo BOM".

Backup your files before u try this.

Comment: I'm using sublime text 2 to send the files in UTF-8 format.  I have also created files directly ON the server through CPanel and the same issue applies.  I didn't downvote you (someone else did) but I don't think your solution would have solved anything... but without testing it myself I actually do not know 100%.  The .htaccess file changes are simple, and work.  I believe they upgraded something on their server and someone got messed up.  After posting this question a few weeks later I had another issue with PDO not working... A config file was in a sub dir and changing settings.

Comment: ... which caused PDO to not work.   Have no idea why but they deleted the extra PHP.ini file and everything started working again.