# Include theme files in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am using an HTML Template, so i want to include js files to the components.

tried adding script tags in index.html

```
  <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i get this console error

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

but css is working fine

also can they be loaded to specific compenents only ? as login component would have a different/less files

any ideas ?

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @Heri edited, please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add external JS scripts to VueJS Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)