# External JS not loading when router.push is executed in vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a project where I have placed the external `js` files like `jquery, datepicker` etc in the 'static' folder. I am importing them in the `index.html` file.

It is getting picked correctly when the page is directly loaded. But when navigating to the page using `$this.router.push('/dashboard')` the `javascript` does not get picked up.

Not sure if I am missing something here

Comment: Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

Comment: Thank you @ljubadr. I'll check it out.