# Add CloudKit JS to Vue Project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-js

I'm trying to add CloudKit JS to a new Vue project. Ideally I'd be able to access CloudKit's functions from any component in my app. I'm brand new to Vue, so please go easy on me. :)

So far, I've tried putting the following in `main.js`:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch')
var CloudKit = require("./cloudkit.js")

CloudKit.configure({
  services: {
    fetch: fetch
  },
  containers: [{
    containerIdentifier: '...',
    apiToken: '...',
    environment: 'development'
  }]
})
```

That gives me a script error in cloudkit.js:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ArrayBuffer' of undefined

So then I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components) and tried this in `App.vue`:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'master': Master
  },
  mounted() {
    let CloudKit = document.createElement('script')
    CloudKit.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/2/cloudkit.js')
    document.head.appendChild(CloudKit)
  }
}
```

I'm then able to configure CloudKit and use it inside `App.vue`, but I'm unclear on how to make CloudKit available in all my components without redefining it as I've done in the `mounted()` function above.

How can I import CloudKit and make it available in my Vue app globally?

Answer (score 1):

Your can add a new global property in vue as well :

Import *CloudKit* as you did then add this in your *main.js* : `Vue.prototype.$CloudKit = CloudKit`

Now, *Cloudkit* is available in your project with `this.$CloudKit`

[More info here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example)

PS: you may configure cloudkit in `mounted` in the app

Answer (score 1):

I might be over-simplifying things, but I tried adding:

```
<script src="https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/2/cloudkit.js"></script>
```

...to the `index.html` file in my Vue project, and it seems to work great. The `CloudKit` object is available in all of my components. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯