# How to use videojs hotkeys plugin in vue component?

Tags: vuejs2, video.js

I use videojs within vue component, it works fine. Then I tried to use [videojs-hotkeys](https://github.com/ctd1500/videojs-hotkeys#options) plugin like

```
<template>
    <video
            id="myplayer"
            poster="xxx.jpg"
            class="video-js"
            controls>
        <source :src="source.src" :type="source.type">
    </video>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import videojs from 'video.js';

    $(function(){
       console.log(this); //Output: object: #document
    });

    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                source: {
                    src:"xxx.mp4",
                    type:""
                }
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log(this);  //Output: Vue Component: vue instance

            //import external script
            let hotkeysScript = document.createElement('script')
            hotkeysScript.setAttribute('src', 'http://cdn.sc.gl/videojs-hotkeys/latest/videojs.hotkeys.min.js')
            document.head.appendChild(hotkeysScript)

            videojs('myplayer').ready(function () {
                console.log(this);                    //Output: player instance
                this.hotkeys({                        //Error: this.hotkeys is not a function
                    volumeStep: 0.1,
                    seekStep: 5,
                    enableModifiersForNumbers: false
                });
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

The browser gave me below error information

```
app.js:107959 Uncaught TypeError: this.hotkeys is not a function
at Player.<anonymous> (app.js:107959)
at Player.<anonymous> (app.js:16325)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Player.<anonymous> (app.js:16324)
at bound (app.js:14739)
at app.js:16992
```

I tried to print the value of "this" in code(please see the comment in code), and gives output for your reference. Please help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add plugins to `videojs` via the `plugins` property  when initialized.

```
videojs('example-player', {
  plugins: {
    examplePlugin: {
      customClass: 'example-class'
    }
  }
});
```

If you need to set some data after the `videojs` instance is ready you can still modify the config the way you are now. You can also store via `this.videoPlayer` and then at anytime access the plugin.

source: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/plugins.md#setting-up-a-plugin

Comment: Hi, I tried your method, use "hotkeys" to replace "examplePlugin" and 'example-class' in your code snippet, but still get Error: plugin "hotkeys" does not exist. [videojs-hotkeys source](https://github.com/ctd1500/videojs-hotkeys/blob/master/videojs.hotkeys.js) for your reference.

Comment: The error is with the way you import. Don't do this. `let hotkeysScript = document.createElement('script'); hotkeysScript.setAttribute('src', 'http://cdn.sc.gl/videojs-hotkeys/latest/videojs.hotkeys.min.js')`. Instead you should store the file locally and `import` it.

Comment: normally, I use npm install xxx, then I can import in vue component like: import { videoPlayer } from 'vue-video-player';. But how can I import external javascript like videojs-hotkeys in Vue compnent? I just refer to [how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components). Then get Error: plugin "hotkeys" does not exist.

Comment: Just now, I tried same code within normal html file, both methods(original & the snippet you provided) works very weill. The issue should be caused by the way I import plugin script, the import sequence also important, it should be import after videojs. So now question becomes "how can I correctly import this plugin in vue component?"

Comment: You import using relative path import, e.g. `import hotkeys from '../scripts/hotkeys'`

Answer (score 0):

I fond there is npm package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-hotkeys, so just install it like

```
npm install videojs-hotkeys --save
```

very simple, for I am not quite family with new features of javascript, just follow the instructions on the home page of the plugin. 
Thanks @Justin Kahn all the same, for helping locate the issue scope.