# How to use Discourse comments in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, discourse

I have a website that uses Vuejs. And a forum in Discourse. I am trying to insert a javascript in the template file that will connect comments from the forum to a specific page on Vuejs site. But I get the error:

```
Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. 
Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, 
as they will not be parsed.
```

My **Detail.vue** code:

```
<div id='discourse-comments'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
DiscourseEmbed = { discourseUrl: 'https://forum.epicseven.ru/',
                 discourseEmbedUrl: '{{url absolute="true"}}' };

(function() {
var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 'text/javascript'; 
d.async = true;
d.src = DiscourseEmbed.discourseUrl + 'javascripts/embed.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);
  })();
</script>
```

I was try change `text/javascript` to `application/javascript`, but when i try render it, i receive error:

```
 - invalid expression: missing ) after argument list in

" \n  DiscourseEmbed = { discourseUrl: 'https://forum.epicseven.ru/',\n                     
discourseEmbedUrl: '"+_s(url absolute="true")+"' };\n\n  (function() {\n    
var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 
'application/javascript'; d.async = true;\n    d.src = 
DiscourseEmbed.discourseUrl + 'javascripts/embed.js';\n    
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);\n  })();\n"

  Raw expression: DiscourseEmbed = { discourseUrl: 
'https://forum.epicseven.ru/',
                 discourseEmbedUrl: '{{url absolute="true"}}' };

  (function() {
    var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 
'application/javascript'; d.async = true;
    d.src = DiscourseEmbed.discourseUrl + 'javascripts/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);
  })();
```

How i can fix this error? Maybe try to use different part of code?

Comment: Why not extract that IIFE into the vue lifecycle methods?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components) question.

Comment: I already try it. Don't work :(