# Add External script into vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to include into my vue.js application a simple javascript script with an external link to the library, this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my_site/index.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my_site/index.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         new Pbx(
             {
                 "key1": 'value1',
                 "key2": 'value2'
             },
             {
                 'config': 'configValue'
             }
         );
     });
 </script>
```

I have this main.js file and I would like to keep external my script:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';
    import App from './App.vue';
    import router from './router';
    import store from './store';
    import i18n from './i18n';
    import VueScrollactive from 'vue-scrollactive';
    import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip';

    import './styles/index.scss';

    export default new Vue({
      el: '#myApp',
      store,
      router,
      i18n,
      render: h => h(App),
    });
```

I would like to know how to include my library in a good way, I have tried to include my javascrupt here but I don't like it so much.

Thanks

Comment: 1. You can include the js file in index.html
2. Or in your App.vue (whatever your main vue component is) - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had used jQuery without installing it in npm, as long as you place `<script>` tag of jQuery on top of `script` tag of the build files that is placed inside the generated html file you may able to access the `$` variable of jQuery inside your app.

You may do something like creating a separate `.js` file for that variable you want to access. `let pbx = new Pbx(data)` and the `pbx` data is accessible throughout the app as long the placing of script tags is proper.

One thing though, `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` might interfere with vue, however you can access the `pbx` variable to the `mounted` life cycle of `App` component if you want to access it immediately