# Importing Stripe.js as an ES Module into Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

[I'm trying follow the directions from the stripe elements docs and install the ES module into my Vue payment component.](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#html-js)

*Note, currently the Stripe websites ES module installation tab is down. [Here's a substitute.](https://dev.to/stripe/importing-stripe-js-as-an-es-module-1ni)*

I ran:

`npm install @stripe/stripe-js`

**Usage**

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');
```

When I change my code to reflect the installation of the module I get this error:

> 30:17  error  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
let stripe = await loadStripe(`pk_test_mypin`)
elements = stripe.elements()
card = undefined;

export default {
    mounted: function () {
        card = elements.create('card', {

        });
        card.mount(this.$refs.card);
    },
    data () {
        return {
            cardHolderName: '',
            stripeErrorMessage: null,
            serverErrorMessage: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
        processPayment(){

            let self = this;

            stripe.createPaymentMethod(
                'card', card, {
                    billing_details: { name: this.cardHolderName }
            }).then(function(result) {

                if(self.subscribitionCheckout){
                    self.submitPaymentForm(result.paymentMethod);
                } else if (self.changePaymentMethod){
                    self.changePaymentMethod(result.paymentMethod)
                }

                if (result.error) {
                    self.stripeErrorMessage = result.error.message;
                    self.hasCardErrors = true;
                    self.$forceUpdate(); // Forcing the DOM to update so the Stripe Element can update.
                return; 
                }
            });

        },
    },
}
```

**Before I had this**

```
let stripe = Stripe(`pk_test_mypin`),
elements = stripe.elements(),
card = undefined;
```

[Also, I based my code on this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-stripe-elements-vue-integration)

Comment: The issue is not about the import, but how you attempt to use it. The error message tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @Sirko, remove the await? This gives me another set of errors that I didn't get with the cdn. Any advice?

Comment: Wrap it inside an async function and call that function somewhere. There are plans for top level await, but afaik it's not supported yet. Just removing `await` changes the behavior. Maybe read up a little on `async/await`.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that and come back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, put the expected top level `vars` in data:

```
stripe: {}, // or whatever data type
elements: {}, // or whatever data type
card: {}, // or whatever data type
```

Second, make a `created` lifecycle hook and load the content there:

```
created()
{
  loadStripe(`pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx`).
  then ( (result) =>
  {
    this.elements = result.elements
    // do stuff with card if you have too...

  },
},
```