# How add javascript file in vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to use in function from javascript file in vue.js project,

I tried to add javascript file to script in component in my  vue.js project and to get access to function but I did not succeed to add my javascript file in correct.

Comment: Does the script have an npm package? How exactly did you add it to your component?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components (dupe)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `javascript` file then `export` you function from that file

```
export const test = ()=> {

  console.log("foo")

}
```

then in your vue component you can just import your function

```
import {test} from "./path/your-file-name"
```