# Load another javascript file in VueJS component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

how can i load **Javascripts** files in **Vue js components** ? (Best way)

Comment: best way? so, what ways have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add external JS scripts to VueJS Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just create `script` element in the `mounted` method :

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
     // ...data of your component
    }),
    mounted() {

      let script1 = document.createElement('script')
      script1.setAttribute('src', 'path/to/file.js')
      script1.async = true
      document.head.appendChild(script1)

    }
  }
</script>
```