# Calling component method in Nuxt from external JS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got an external code that calls on a specific function name `someEvent()` and I cannot change this file as it belongs externally.

Currently, I have defined the function `someEvent()` in a separate `a.js` file in the `@/static` folder:

```
function someEvent(e) {
    // I want to call my Nuxt page methods here
}
```

and included in my `head()`:

```
export default {
    head() {
         script: [
             { src: 'a.js' }
         ],
    }
}
```

How do I call my `index.vue` methods here in this `a.js`? Or if you have a better method, I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

Comment: Hi, I can include the files, but what I want to do is for a.js to call my component methods. Thanks for the link however