# How can I read the js script in Vue/Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Example Code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<widget_id>.js" async defer></script>
```

I want to add to Quasar Framework and use the js in Vue. Any idea to add?
Example I want to add inside this script in Quasar:

```js
<script>
export default {
   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case I added the script to my component via the mounted method.

```
let widgetScript = document.createElement('script')
widgetScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/') 
document.head.appendChild(widgetScript)
```

Just look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002863)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" :src="'https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/' + widget_id + '.js'" async defer/>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some context and explanation of your solution, rather than just a code fragment. You are more likely to get upvoted if people understand why your solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

Within the **mounted()** method, you can use the `document.createElement()` and `document.head.appendChild()` methods to dynamically create a ***script*** tag and append it to the ***head*** section of the document.

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<widget_id>.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  },
};
```