# Conditionally add a JS script?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to include an external script depending on a var:

```
<div v-if="shouldInclude">
    <script src="/my-script.js"></script>
</div>
```

Yet according to the network panel, the script is loaded when `shouldInclude` is both true and false.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: DOM rendering happens before the component creates itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add external JS scripts to VueJS Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `require` instead, and place it inside a lifecycle hook.

```
created: function () {
    if (this.shouldInclude) {
      require('./my-script.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - is there no way to do this in a template?

Comment: Not really, since it's bundled by webpack. You could however do something like this: `<%= process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '<script>...</script>' : '' %>`

Comment: In Vue `v2.6.11`, trying to include a `<script>` tag within a template makes the compiler complain:

`Error compiling template:`
`<div id="app"><script src="included.js"></script></div>`

`- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.`
`Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, `
`as they will not be parsed.`
`