# External javascript from public/index.html not loading in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use Mathjax on my website. I put in the `<head>` section of `public/index.html`:

```
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

And, in my component :

```
<template>
    <div v-html="note_content"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { typeset, dummy_typeset } from '../assets/js/text_processing.js';
import showdown from 'showdown';

const converter = new showdown.Converter({ tables: true });

export default {
    data () {
        return {
        }
    },
    computed: {
        note_content: function() {
            return typeset(this.exchange_data);
        }
    },
    props: ['exchange_data'],
    watch: {
        note_content: function() {
            Mathjax.typesetPromise();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However on runtime, I get the error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Mathjax is not defined
```

What I do not understand is that the css which is located in the `head` of `public/index.html` is correctly loaded and rendered in the component. Also I read elsewhere that loading external javascript this way should make it available to all components. What is wrong ?

Comment: have you tried without the `async` attribute?

Comment: yes, still get Mathjax not defined.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I'm having a comparable problem on Firefox.  It might be a Firefox-compatibility issue: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrarily to what is written at https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html, the syntax for asynchronous rendering is not :

```
Mathjax.typesetPromise()
```

But (notice the case):

```
MathJax.typesetPromise()
```

The typo could be detected from the surrounding context.

Also not that to use typeset Mathjax in a Vue component, the virtual DOM should be processed before calling the `typesetPromise` method, so an example of working code would be:

```
watch: {
    note_content: function() {
        this.$nextTick(MathJax.typesetPromise);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is connected to webpack config, but i might be wrong. Anyway, have you tried this method?

[How to add external JS scripts to VueJS Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

It enforces the script to be loaded.

Comment: I tried to put the mathjax javascript in the `src/assets` directory and then load it using `import '../assets/ext/polyfill.min.js?features=es6'`; and `import '../assets/ext/tex-mml-chtml.js';` . I still gt the error that Mathjax is undefined, but now the imports are being processed.

Comment: Since I changed my approach I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215530/import-bundled-mathjax-in-vue-component

Comment: Thank to your answer I understood that public is not processed by webpack and I am moving resources into `src/assets`.

Comment: I'm happy it worked out. Good luck with the project!

Comment: I found the bug, this is ridiculous.