# How do you import a cdn as an es6 module in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework

In a non Vue3 application this works as expected
I am using the Quasarjs framework which runs Vue

```
  <script type='module'>
    import * as Magick from 'https://knicknic.github.io/wasm-imagemagick/magickApi.js';
    Magick.whatever()
  </script>
```

How do I get that to work inside a Vue component?

I need it to be a cdn and not a reference to an npm module

Comment: Is your code in a Single File Component? Are you getting errors? Why couldn't it be installed as a npm dependency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add external JS scripts to VueJS Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components)

Comment: I went a different direction and used vite which allowed me to import it like above.  But yes the link would answer my question, thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how you imported it? I am trying to do it too, having difficulties with the npm package

Comment: I actually switched to wasm-libvips.  I like it better but one downside is that you have to configure your server for the SharredArrayBuffer origin.  See https://github.com/kleisauke/wasm-vips.  For some reason he has not fixed the browser version for npm so I just copied the javascript files from his example.  See my repo https://github.com/delebash/unreal_mapbox_bridge.  In the public directory are the 3 vip files you need.  I added vips to my index.html src="vips.js".  Then in code src>components>side-nav.  I declaared a vips variable and initialized in mounted,  Hope this helps